# Limitations of std::result_of for lambdas in C++14

Tags: c++, c++14

I have a working piece of C++17 code that I would like to port to C++14 (project's constraints). The code allocates a functor on the heap, based on the lambda returned by a provider.

```
decltype(auto) fun_provider(std::string msg)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
{
    return [msg](){ std::cout << msg << std::endl; };
}

int main()
{
    auto fun = std::make_unique<
                    std::invoke_result_t<decltype(fun_provider), std::string>
                   >(fun_provider("Provided functor"));
    (*fun.get())()
}
// output: "Provided functor"
```

The point is, it avoids hardcoding lambda type as `std::function<void()>`. Up to my best knowledge, the closure type is unspecified and such construction would imply unnecessary copy of the closure object (hope that's correct).

I would like to achieve the same goal with C++14, is it possible? I tried few constructions with `std::result_of` and/or `decltype` but didn't succeed so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this approach not viable?

```cpp
    auto fun = std::make_unique<
                    decltype(fun_provider(std::declval<std::string>()))
                   >(fun_provider("Provided functor"));
```

The use of `std::declval` isn't even necessary; `std::string{}` instead of `std::declval<std::string>()` is just fine.

Comment: It works, thanks! Perhaps I was trying to over-engineer the problem when trying on my own.

Answer (score 5):

How about routing `fun_provider`'s return value through another pass of template deduction?

```
template <class T>
auto to_unique(T&& orig) {
    using BaseType = std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<T>>;
    return std::make_unique<BaseType>(std::forward<T>(orig));
}

int main()
{
    auto fun = to_unique(fun_provider("Provided functor"));
    (*fun.get())();
}
```

Comment: I preferred the answer below (accepted) but your reply is also didactic, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just for the sake of completeness and to answer the original question.

The correct solution using `std::result_of_t` would look like this:

```
auto fun = std::make_unique<
              std::result_of_t<decltype(&fun_provider)(std::string)>
             >(fun_provider("Provided functor"));
```